# Using Snowpark in Streamlit: Incorrect username or password was specified

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, streamlit

I'm trying to output a dataframe from my Streamlit app directly into Snowflake. I have my `.streamlit/secrets.toml` file, and I connect to Snowpark with:

```
import streamlit as st

# Initialize connection to Snowflake
conn = st.experimental_connection('snowpark')
```

However, I get this error:

```
snowflake.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 250001 (08001): Failed to connect to DB: XX12345.eu-west-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443. Incorrect username or password was specified.
```

My username/password is correct, and I suspect the error comes from the fact that I sign in to snowflake with AzureAD SSO. Is there another way to connect Streamlit to Snowpark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the secrets.toml file, the following parameter would need to be added
"authenticator=externalbrowser" so that authentication module would use the AD credentials and then pass the token to the Streamlit session.

Another option in case this is not feasible is to use OAuth as detailed here https://medium.com/snowflake/snowflake-oauth-for-streamlit-e95e4cb3de6c and then change the value in the secrets.toml as follows:

authenticator=oauth

the code example for python based connection for OAuth is here: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Test-Azure-OAuth-Connection-To-Snowflake-End-To-End-Using-Python-User-Credentials-Flow